# WPF User Control space not being used by others when it is collapsed

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, datagrid, user-controls, grid

In my main WPF Window I have below distribution:

```
<Border BorderBrush="SkyBlue"
        Background="White"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="20 0 0 0">

        <DockPanel>

            <Border x:Name="WindowTitleBar"  
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    CornerRadius="20 0 0 0"                                        
                    Background="LightBlue">

                    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">

                    <!-- Here are textblocks and a status bar simulating a window title bar with maximize, minimize and close buttons -->

                    </DockPanel>                    
            </Border>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />    <!-- Content -->                
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" /> <!-- Status bar at bottom -->                   
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                           
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.60*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.47*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <controls:MyUC_01 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"                                                
                                          Width="auto"
                                          Height="auto"
                                          DataContext="{Binding}" />

                        <controls:MyUC_02 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                          Width="auto"
                                          Height="auto"
                                          DataContext="{Binding}" />        

                        <controls:MyUC_03 Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"   
                                          Width="auto"
                                          Height="auto"
                                          DataContext="{Binding}" />

                        <Expander Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                  Grid.Column="1"       
                                  Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"
                                  Expanded="Expander_Expanded"
                                  ExpandDirection="Left"
                                  IsExpanded="True">

                                  <!-- Expander content -->
                        </Expander>                               

                    </Grid>

                    <!-- BELOW SPACE OCCUPIED BY UCMessage KEEP BLANK WHEN VIEW MODEL PROPERTY MessageVisibility IS SET TO COLLAPSE -->
                    <controls:UCMessage Grid.Row="1" x:Name="UCMessage"
                                        Width="auto"
                                        Height="auto"
                                        DataContext="{Binding}" 
                                        Visibility="{Binding Path=MessageVisibility}" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

When user control UCMessage is collapsed (depending on the MessageVisibility view model property value), its space is not used by the rest of controls and it remains blank. Even when resizing the window, this space is not used by others. The row where UCMessage is placed is set to height=auto but it is not working.

Below the above distribution as an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code for the binding of "MessageVisibility"... is the value set to "Hidden" or "Collapsed".  They are two separate things... Hidden means retain the space even if not shown.  Collapsed is don't show and don't retain space unless it is explicitly needed and thus made visible.

If that does not work, sometimes I have noticed bindings may not be what they appear.  If your message binding is to the main data context and not to some child/property of the user control itself, you MIGHT need to wrap it such as

```
<UserControl Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=MessageVisibility}">
    <controls:UCMessage 
        x:Name="UCMessage"
        Width="auto"
        Height="auto"
        DataContext="{Binding}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I have seen that it is due I have set width and height to a fixed value for the main window. So I have used SizeToContent="Height" but then MinHeight it is not respected... Anyway each user control is not being resized its height when window is resized... and I do not know why...